# Trying to see default handlers for various signals

Tags: signals

I understand that there is a default signal handler, that is a function for each signal , such as SIGKILL etc. In which file it is written? 
I tried looking at signal.h, but could not find it there.

I am expecting each signal handler is having at least one function (handler).

Kindly help me locate this file

Answer (score 7):

There is no "file" like you want to see, unless you want to read kernel code.

This is a little oversimplified.  See the chapter in Rago & Stevens on Signals in 'Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment' for a lot more information.

There are two parts to 'default signal handling'.  These are built into the kernel.
When the scheduler notices that there is a pending signal for a process, it gives the process the cpu if necessary (a context switch).  Next the signal is delivered to the process.  The process has a signal mask which allows it to ignore a lot of signals if the mask is deliberately set, two signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be ignored or blocked.  So the process now has a signal.  If there is no handler set the kernel takes the default action for the signal.

There is a list of default actions for signals.  SIGSEGV, for instance, terminates the process after it has dumped core.  Michael Kerrisk has an explanation of the default actions.  This is what I think you want.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

The kernel has code to handle all of these signal's default responses for the process.

If the kernel gets a signal  for "itself" (depending on what flavor of UNIX we are talking about) the kernel panics,  writes a crash dump, and leaves you with headache. - which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually want to access kernel code. so there has to be default definitions for each handler. Where is that?

Comment: What operating system do you have?